# Error when starting Nodemon on my server.js file (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, terminal, node-modules, nodemon

I recently started getting an error in my terminal when I start nodemon on my server.js file within my directory. Here is a picture below [image]

Here is the error.

```
    dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _node_module_register
    Referenced from: /Users/dan/nodeStuff/crm-test/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/build/Release/bson.node
    Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

Not sure what the issue is. I did a brew update and also made sure my port was correct.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who stumbles by this problem, I had the same issue when trying to start my server with nodemon.

For me, the problem was I was still using an older version of node with nvm. I switched back to the version appropriate for my application and problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running `node server.js`?

Maybe it's not nodemon.

Comment: Hey yes I have. Nodemon is just a simply way so that I don't need to restart node server.js everytime I touch a file.

Comment: What I think Javier implied it's not related to nodemon, so it should not be a part of the question. Unless you say that there is no error when starting with  `node server.js`, but yes when you do `nodemon server.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked around and I did a npm rebuild which helped. When I start nodemon server.js or node server.js it tells me that one of the packages I was using is depreciated, I'm guessing that's what threw the error. Not sure why body-parser is depreciated.

Comment: Take a look at Express.js and body-parser npm module to see why. (Of course, also your module versions).